# Tag link suggestion plugin

Tags: plugins, posts, tags, links

Every time I write a post I make sure I add links to words that I have tags for.

For example:
"The economy of [Brazil](http://blog.antinovaordemmundial.com/tag/brasil) has improved in the last few years".

This ensures that when people re-post my content, a lot of back-links will be created to my tags. This is quite a lot of work to do manually for every post.

It would be cool if there was a plugin that would suggest tags to be applied when they match existing words in the text of the post.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

I ran a [search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=automatic+tag+link) on the wordpress plugin directory there are several options.

[Terms to Links](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/terms-to-links/) looks like it should work for you. It automatically links to terms in your content to that term's page. Can be used for tags, categories and custom taxonomies.

Comment: The problem of terms to links is that it will add all matching terms, which can be too much most of times. I try always to not overload the texto with links, and this would be exactly what would happen with this plugin.